# How to properly use jQuery in Notepad++?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently learning HTML, CSS, a bit of jQuery and trying to build a website. I'm using Notepad++ and HTML, CSS code is working properly. Now I'm trying to implement some jQuery code for some animations and it doesn't seem to work very well. I've created a div and named it "header" using ID. I've set up all the CSS code and now trying to make it fade to 1 opacity when I hover my mouse on (I've set opacity to 0.5 in CSS).

`#header {
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    width: 1100px;
    height: 110px;
    margin-top: -130px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    background-color: #e68a00;
    opacity: 0.5;
}`

`$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#header").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 1)
    });
    $("#header").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#header").fadeTo('fast', 0.5)
    });
});`

But for some reason it doesn't work for me. Didn't enable jQuery right or my code is wrong?

Here's my linking:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S English isn't my first language therefore I apologize if my grammar isn't correct.

Comment: can you paste your complete code in js fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must also link the jquery file in your code. Go to the following link and download the version you need.
https://jquery.com/download/

Then place a reference to the files above your script.js file.

Comment: I concur, your code works, you just need to import jquery.js first.